# "That comes to $120" vs. "that comes out to $120"

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Would you please tell me if there is any difference between *come to* and *come out to* when doing calculations? For example:

> Head phones costs $25 and the phone phone $95. That **comes to** $120.
>
> Head phones costs $25 and the phone phone $95. That **comes out to** $120.

According to dictionaries' definitions they mean the same thing to me. Do they? Are there contexts where native speakers of English would use one rather than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have the same basic meaning, and I can't think of any context where one is correct and the other incorrect when describing the result of a calculation.

That said, if you're looking for shades of difference, I feel a strong preference to use "that comes to" to describe simple addition or subtraction, and "that comes out to" to express the result of more complex calculations.

Supporting my feeling, in a [Google Books search for "that comes out to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22that%20comes%20out%20to%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2008,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en), every hit that uses this structure in the first few pages expresses the result of a more complex calculation than addition or subtraction.

There are too many hits for "that comes to" that aren't calculations to make a direct comparison, but it seems reasonable to me that among all statements in books expressing a calculation result, a significant portion of them should be from addition and subtraction, but with "that comes out to", we find few to none.

Comment: The ngram search is completely unreliable. As noted in my answer, there are too many other contexts that use that string of words. "I know a doctor *that comes out to* your house". "The gay child *that comes out to* their parents..."

Comment: @Astralbee It was a Google Books search, not Ngrams, and I only referred to examples where *the text introduced the results of calculations*, not visits from doctors. There were no hits with simple addition or subtraction. That fact is significant. Further, I presented that as supporting my feeling about the two forms. My feeling as a native speaker is the primary evidence. If you think my feeling is incorrect, then it would be helpful for you to say that.

Answer (score 1):

British English speaker here, and I have *never* heard anyone say "*comes out to*" in this context. I think you may have mixed up two different idiomatic sayings.

"*That comes to $120*" is perfectly idiomatic when giving the total of individual monetary values.

The phrase I think this may have got mixed up with is "*comes out **at***". This is a way some people refer to a total from a device such as a calculator or a cash register. For example, "*I ran the numbers and it came out at [x]*".

Note that there are other entirely unrelated contexts in which you might use these phrases. My answer is in reference to this precise context.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Could you please tell me if it would sound unnatural to say "I ran the numbers and it came to [x]"?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-out-at-to

Comment: @Mari-LouA That is a huge surprise to see it in the Cambridge. Interesting that the example in this chiefly British English dictionary uses dollars. I suspect it may be a US inclusion lifted from another dictionary. The entry is, after all, for both 'at' and 'to' and notes that the expressions are both UK and US.